# Kingston compact flash card won't mount in a computer (Win7/OS X/Ubuntu)

Tags: compactflash, file-recovery

I took photos today using a Canon 50D with a 64 GB Kingston card.  When I turned on the camera after I got home, it said that the card was not formatted.  I could not mount the file system using a USB CF card reader either using Windows 7, OS X Yosemite, or Ubuntu 15.04 .

When I tried to use recovery software (e.g., PhotoRec, and TestDisk), it didn't work because it could not find the drive to begin with.

Comment: Have you try to use USB cable and check if the card can be read via camera?

Comment: Romeo: yes I tried but had no luck.  The files don't show up on the computer either.

Comment: You can do few more check: use another reader, try few shots with other CF card and check if they are readable

Comment: Yes I did.  When I put an older CF card into the camera and into the card reader, it can be read -(

Comment: I think the CF card is toast, because when I could not even get my 50D camera to format the card!

Comment: wsw - this, last, is bad news. For me this mean card is out :(

Comment: Agreed.  The worst part is that I have to spend 2 hours retaking the photos tomorrow.  I am definitely not buying Kingston products again, as the faulty CF card is barely 1 year old.

Comment: Sounds like the card is dead. This is usually due to the wires inside, not the real flash ram itself, and could be recovered professionally.  Be sure to complain to Kingston: you pay for the name-brand, take them up on the lifetime warranty!  Also beware of counterfit cards.

Comment: Note that when a Canon camera is connected to your computer via USB it will not show up as a drive. The only way to download images directly off the camera is to use *EOS Utility* (remember that disc of applications that came with your camera?) or another utility written specifically to enable a Canon camera and your computer to communicate. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45141/15871

Comment: Michael: not true -- when I connect my Canon 50D or my old Canon S70 to a Mac, I can see the directories on the CF card.  I have been using CF cards since 2000 but have tried to stay away from installing any custom software.

Comment: It may well be the card is defective, but it could also be that you removed or inserted it when the camera or card reader was attempting a write operation. This has the potential of bricking a perfectly good card. The camera should *ALWAYS* be turned off when inserting/removing a CF card. And always dismount a CF card before removing it from a reader. I prefer to only insert/remove a CF card from an internal reader if the computer is not running. It may be a little paranoid, but I've never fried a CF card.

Comment: @wsw then in that case your MAC has some specific additional code included that allows the camera to be used with the PIMA 15740-2000 protocol. And although I'm not a MAC guy many of my photographer friends are and you are the first person I've ever seen that claims an EOS camera will show up as a logical drive on MAC without installing additional code to allow the PIMA 15740-2000 to be functional with an EOS camera.

Comment: If the photos still show up on the card and can be viewed on the camera's LCD screen I'm willing to bet that using EOS Utility will allow you to transfer them to your computer.

Comment: And, as JDlugosv alluded to, just becasue a card is labeled "Kingston" doesn't mean it is a genuine Kingston CF card. The two most counterfeited brands of cards are SanDisk and Kingston. Unless you buy them from a reputable source the chances are very high a CF card is fake. That's why I don't but any CF cards on eBay.

Comment: Michael: no, I could not get the 50D or my old S70 to recognize the CF card.  In fact, as I said early, I could not even format the card using my 50D.  Btw I bought the card on Amazon for about $50 11 months ago.

Comment: I have owned several CF cards since the 8 MB (yes MB) one I bought in 2000 but never had a problem until recently.  I forgot to say that, during a shoot a couple of months ago, a few image files were corrupted when they were written by the camera to the card; I didn't think much about it, thinking that it was a one-off problem.

Comment: I am buying a SanDisk CF card as a replacement: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00NUB2RPW .

Comment: Did you try to recover with testdisk? Maybe the partition of the card is corrupt. I always use lexar cards, i have the silly idea that these cards dont have fake copies.

Comment: krivos: yes, I tried.  As I wrote in my original question, when "I tried to use recovery software (e.g., PhotoRec, and TestDisk), it didn't work because it could not find the drive to begin with."

Answer (score 1):

I know I am replying to this post late in the game, but it sounds like the card data may still be able to be recovered by a data recovery lab. they would have the expertise to be able to do "surgery" on the card and get to the memory.